# How to add input to array and stop when user inputs the string 'stop'?

Tags: c, string, input, while-loop

In school we use the integer -999 to stop `scanf` and end the inputs that user put in the array.

For example:

```
while(input != -999) {
  scanf("%i", &input)
  userArray[i] = input;
  i++;
}
```

I'm thinking about asking the user for string input and converting the input to an integer (using `atoi` in stdlib) as long as the input is not 'stop'.

**Would this be a good idea? Is there a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading in as a string and converting it to an `int` is actually preferable, as it avoids the potential pitfalls associated with the peculiarities of `scanf`

Instead use `fgets`, which reads a line of input.  This function adds the newline character to the input string, so be sure to trim that off before you do anything else.  Once you've done that, you can use `strcmp` to see if the string is equal to "stop", and if not then call `atoi`, or better yet `strtol` (which has better error checking) to get the numerical value.

Comment: Definitely use `strtol` instead of `atoi`.  +1 for that

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way to stop a loop when you are reading an unknown number of inputs *(also as C++ Prime by Stanly B. Lippman says)* you should try to use the "invalid input" or end-of-file solution (if you wanna use a little of C++).

You can use this sintax:

```
while(std::cin >> input) {
  userArray[i] = input;
  i++;
}
```

- **end-of-file:**

If you are on Windows systems we enter an end-of-file by typing a `control-z` (hold down Ctrl key and press z). On UNIX system, including on OS X machines, end-of-file is usually `control-d`

- **invalid input:**

So whenever you type a float point number or any other type that it is not a int for your input, the loop will end.

*PS: This works for C++, so I really don't know if it will work fine in C.*

Comment: There's no such thing as `std::cin` in C, all the things it depends on are lacking: classes, operator overloads, references

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, that is true, so I think this answer would be more about C++ and not so helpful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

How to stop the loop when the input is "stop":

You will be using the `string.h` library.

```
do{
  scanf("%s", input)
  userArray[i] = input;
  i++;
} while(strcmp(input, "stop") != 0);
```

strcmp compares the array `input` to the string "stop", as long as the input is not "stop" it will continue to keep on running.

as recommended by dbush, use fgets, it will be much better.

Comment: Edited post with better grammar, and possibly a better explanation. BTW this is all assuming that input is a `char` array.

Comment: I doubt this would work as it should. If I enter "stop" in console, it'd first store the value into the array, then in the next iteration the while loop won't execute.

Comment: Should be `scanf("%s", input);` since an array already decays to a pointer, and `userarray[i]= input;` attempts to assign incompatible types: some sort of parsing is needed.

Comment: changed it do a do while loop, and removed the `&` from the scanf, can't believe I missed that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I like to use:-

```
while(true)
{
scanf("%s", input);
if(!strcmp(input, "stop"))
    break;
userarray[i]= input;
i++;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (strcmp(input, "stop") == 0)`?

Comment: No. `if(strcmp(input, "stop"))` means if the result returned by strcmp() comparision is true, then do something, in my case it would break from the while loop.

Comment: The condition you posted means if the result returned is false, then break from the loop, which means the input provided by user is something else other than "stop".

Comment: `strcmp()` returns 0 on equality. See [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) reference.

Comment: Thankyou, I mixed it up with java comparison. This is logically so wrong to return false when the strings match each other!

Comment: Should be `scanf("%s", input);` since an array already decays to a pointer, and `userarray[i]= input;` attempts to assign incompatible types: some sort of parsing is needed.  (Oh, now I see you copied these mistakes from another answer)

Comment: I fixed the scanf part. For the `userarray`, I'm assuming it is a 2D character array and the `input` variable is 1D character array. So it should not have a problem.